# Colorify polygons in a pythonic way in Qgis

Tags: qgis, python

I want to addd a Layer  and give the layer a color for the border and for the filling. With the code below i am possible to achieve a color for the border, but a did not found a solution to give a color for the filling. In addition, is it possible to change the width of the border line?

```
uri.setDataSource("shema_name", "layer_name", "geom","","layer_name_id")
lyr = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "layer_name_you_like", "postgres")

props = { 'color_border' : '255,165,0,125', 'style' : 'no', 'style_border' : 'solid' }
s = QgsFillSymbolV2.createSimple(props)
lyr.setRendererV2( QgsSingleSymbolRendererV2( s ) )

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(lyr)
```

Answer (score 3):

I partially solved my question. Looking at a .qgs file properties to rendererV2 look e.g.:

```
 <renderer-v2 symbollevels="0" type="singleSymbol">
            <symbols>
                <symbol outputUnit="MM" alpha="0.3803921568627451" type="fill" name="0">
                    <layer pass="0" class="SimpleFill" locked="0">
                        <prop k="color" v="255,165,0,97"/>
                        <prop k="color_border" v="255,165,0,97"/>
                        <prop k="offset" v="0,0"/>
                        <prop k="style" v="solid"/>
                        <prop k="style_border" v="solid"/>
                        <prop k="width_border" v="1"/>
                    </layer>
                </symbol>
            </symbols>
            <rotation field=""/>
            <sizescale field=""/>
        </renderer-v2>
```

Thus, setting properties assigned with the prop-tag is clear now. However, what ist the phytonic way to set the properties in layer- tag and the the symbol-tag.