# How can i set Vector layer Fill as Transparent Fill in QGIS with Python

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, transparency-opacity

I want to fill vector layer as transparent fill. I am using following code but it fills it with white colour and inner boundaries for vector layer get hid

Code i am using :

```
   from PyQt4 import QtGui      
   layer = iface.addVectorLayer("path_to_vector_layer", "layer_name", "ogr") 
   myVectorLayer = iface.activeLayer()
   myRenderer  = myVectorLayer.rendererV2()

   if myVectorLayer.geometryType() == QGis.Polygon:

     mySymbol1 = QgsFillSymbolV2.createSimple({'color':'#ffffff', 
                                      'color_border':'#000000',
                                      'width_border':'0.6'})
   myRenderer.setSymbol(mySymbol1)
   myVectorLayer.triggerRepaint()
```

Answer (score 8):

Try replacing

```
'color':'#ffffff'
```

with

```
'color':'0,0,0,0'
```

The last zero is the alpha chanel which controls the level of transparency. So setting it to `0` will set the fill colour with an opacity of 0%.

---

Tested with the following code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui      
layer = iface.addVectorLayer("path_to_vector_layer", "layer_name", "ogr") 
myVectorLayer = iface.activeLayer()
myRenderer  = myVectorLayer.rendererV2()
if myVectorLayer.geometryType() == QGis.Polygon:
    mySymbol1 = QgsFillSymbolV2.createSimple({'color':'255,0,0,0',
        'color_border':'#000000',
        'width_border':'0.6'})

myRenderer.setSymbol(mySymbol1)
myVectorLayer.triggerRepaint()
iface.legendInterface().refreshLayerSymbology(myVectorLayer)
```

Comment: It works! Is there a documentation for the Parameter of createSimple? I mean, how do i know the possible members of that dict?

Comment: @AndreasMüller - Glad it worked for you :). Hmm I'm struggling to find any documents regarding the parameters for `createSimple()`. But [this post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74075/colorify-polygons-in-a-pythonic-way-in-qgis) descirbes a number of the parameters involved.

Comment: That's exactly my experience. As a none C++-Programmer it is hard to find answers studing the source code, like here: https://qgis.org/api/qgssymbollayerv2utils_8cpp_source.html, line 48, where i could find the answer... So, thank you!

Comment: @AndreasMüller - If you use the following `myVectorLayer.rendererV2().symbols()[0].symbolLayer(0).properties()`, it prints out the names and values of the parameters which could be used =)

Comment: Very nice! Thank you, again! This could be helpfull with other objects, too!

Comment: @AndreasMüller - Most welcome! Hope it will be ;)